# Is there any need to run Bootstrap in GII?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, yii

If there is a need to run Gii for bootstrap then which generator should I run and by which name I should run?

Here is my code:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');

return array(
'theme'=>'bootstrap', // requires you to copy the theme under your themes directory
'modules'=>array(
    'gii'=>array(
        'generatorPaths'=>array(
            'bootstrap.gii',
        ),
    ),
),
'components'=>array(
    'bootstrap'=>array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
    ),
),
);
```

Comment: anyone plz do help. i am struggling in it

Answer (score 0):

```
`enter code here` 'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'admin',
            'generatorPaths'=>array(
                'bootstrap.gii',
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: You should try explaining what your answer does.